# Writing parser with | parse kind=regex operator

Tags: kql, azure-log-analytics, azure-sentinel, fortigate

I`m trying to make a parser for FortiAnalyzer. I recieve log in next format (example from Fortinet documentation) : 2020-05-12 17:01:16 log_id=0001010018 type=event subtype=system pri=information desc="User login/logout successful" user="admin" userfrom="JSON(10.100.55.254)" msg="user 'admin' with profile 'Super_User' logout from JSON(10.100.55.254)" session_id=5108 adminprof="Super_User"

So variable=value . There are about 30-40 variables and they order may vary.

So i parse information in next way :
| parse kind=regex (name_of_my_column) with * "log_id" * "=" Log_ID: string "type=" Type: string  "subtype=" Subtype: string and so on.... When i write 17 variables in one query it gives me an error :
parse: regex mode exceeded max allowed matching groups. actual = 17, limit = 16
When i start new line with | parse kind=regex function, previous variable (#16) has all information that comes after variable #16
Variable #17 has the right information.
[end of first query with | parse kind=regex and start of a second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxT0B.png)
[information in variable #16 and #17](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIuA5.png)
Can someone please give an advice, what should i add to my query to see results in right way?
I also tried to use |extend function, but i think, that is not right way in my case because variables can be in different positions in log.
Will be thankful to any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the [`parse-kv` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/parse-kv-operator).

for example:

````
print input = ```2020-05-12 17:01:16 log_id=0001010018 type=event subtype=system pri=information desc="User login/logout successful" user="admin" userfrom="JSON(10.100.55.254)" msg="user 'admin' with profile 'Super_User' logout from JSON(10.100.55.254)" session_id=5108 adminprof="Super_User"```
| parse-kv input as (log_id:string, type:string, subtype:string, pri:string, ['desc']:string, user:string, userfrom:string, msg:string, session_id:long, adminprof:string) with (pair_delimiter=' ', kv_delimiter='=', quote='"')
| project-away input
````

| log_id | type | subtype | pri | desc | user | userfrom | msg | session_id | adminprof |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0001010018 | event | system | information | User login/logout successful | admin | JSON(10.100.55.254) | user 'admin' with profile 'Super_User' logout from JSON(10.100.55.254) | 5108 | Super_User |